# What is the algorithm behind minimum_spanning_arborescence in networkx?

Tags: python, networkx

As far I know the usual algorithms used to evaluate the arborescence in directed graphs are initiated with a "beginning node". It is not clear for me the algorithm that is used. Can you help me?

Comment: https://networkx.github.io/documentation/latest/_modules/networkx/algorithms/tree/branchings.html